# fprint doens't work in my php

Tags: php, stdout, printf, fclose

I want to write some text from script in browser.

```
<?php
$out = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fprintf($out, "Hello!");
fclose($out);
?>
```

I expect "Hello!" on output, but nothing happens...Could it be bug in stdout, or I just oversighted something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be true if calling php from console.

But if you are talking about web access, you should use `php://output`

Comment: Its not on only console .. it worked over the browser too http://codepad.org/wG9f537v

Comment: Hi Petr and Baba! Thank you very much, It works! Have a nice rest of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simple :

```
<?php
$out = "foobar";
echo $out;
?>
```

?

By default, php print on `STDOUT`.